# Accessing widgets inside QStackedWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing a Qt app with QtDesigner.

Previously it was quite easy to access specific widgets to do something with them like connecting signals. After I added QStackedWidget I can no longer access specific widgets with something like ui->stack->page1->widget.

Is there a way to do it somehow? Or should I always call findChild method? Or maybe it is possible to at least assign some of the nested widgets in stack widget to properties of the main windwo class?

Comment: `QStackedWidget` has `currentWidget()` and `widget()` methods, which seem perfectly suited for what you're describing.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar, I accidentally wrote the answer without seeing your comment. If you want to answer, I can delete mine.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh : That's fine, enjoy your upvote. :)

Answer (score 2):

QStackedWidget provides a method to get [child widgets by index](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#widget), as well as the [current widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html#currentWidget).

A quick example is as follows:

**MOCed Header**

```
class MyWidget: QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    using QWidget::QWidget

    QWidget *ptr;
};
```

**Source File**

```
QStackedWidget *stackedWidget = new QStackedWidget;
stackedWidget->addWidget(new MyWidget);     // index 0
stackedWidget->addWidget(new QWidget);      // index 1
stackedWidget->addWidget(new MyWidget);     // index 2

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(stackedWidget);
setLayout(layout);

// do something specific with the first widget's ptr element
auto* widget = stackedWidget->widget(0);
auto* mywidget = qobject_cast<MyWidget*>(widget);
if (mywidget) {
    mywidget->ptr->setObjectName("FirstPage");    
}
```

Now, Qt uses virtual interfaces by default, so if you have a custom subwidget you need to extract, you can use [qobject_cast](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast). qobject_cast is basically a fast dynamic_cast, and works even without RTTI. In template-driven code, `dynamic_cast` is a bit of a code-smell: it means you lost useful type information too early. With virtual interfaces, the exact opposite is true: you should use `qobject_cast` as needed.

Comment: thats is clear but what if I had to access some widget inside widget(0). So for example in designer I have a page in stacked widget with widget called progressBar and I need to access it. I would like to do something like: ui->stackedWIdget->widget(0)->progressBar

Comment: @pshemu, Updated my example, but that is an entirely different question.

Comment: So far I came up with something like this: frame = ui->stackedWidget->widget(6)->findChild<QLabel*>("frame"); But it would be great if I could just do ui->stackedWidget->widget(6)->frame?

Comment: `findChild` is just going to call the equivalent of qobject_cast anyway internally (it doesn't directly call `qobject_cast`, but uses the same Qt metaobject system). If you already know the index, just do `qobject_cast` manually. Virtual interfaces don't work like that, @pshemu. That's not how this works. The entire point of a virtual interface is that it can store any class using virtual overloads and call these specialized methods from only the base class. All the stacked widget knows is the base class. You have to then cast this base class to your known type derived type.

Comment: Very simply, @pshemu, the QStackedWidget only knows the base class exists (QWidget), which has certain virtual methods from derived classes. It knows these exist by their signature and offset, so it can call them, but it has absolutely **no** idea about your derived class. To cast to the derived class, you **must** cast. `findChild` is a template function, it calls a cast. `qobject_cast` is a cast, it casts the object. Both are safe casts. You must cast.

Comment: that is clear, but since Qt designer knows which widgets I have used in the stacked widget, couldn't ui instance provide already objects of proper class? but anyway I will cast.

Answer (score 2):

Why you get the widget layer by layer, if your widgets are added in Qt designer, you can get it by `ui->widget` directly.